# Preview is not showing for some activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-rendering

Preview is not showing for some XML files in android studio but the application works fine. In order to develop my application, I need to be able to see all preview properly

I've read several posts in StackOverflow 
I change style, sdk ,but it doesn't work any way

Here are some rendering error android studio gave me

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException@53dcf95b
>           java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@24df40fa
>           java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@269b81fb

Comment: try clean and build.

Comment: maybe you need to change the android API that you are using

Comment: Sorry, I've tried all but it's doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

For me I switching to text to design again and again. And sometime switching to preview and gradle at the right corner. This does the trick. Hope it help you

Answer (score 1):

You may try some options:

- Clean Project
- Rebuild Project
- Invalidate caches / Restart
- Switching Multiple time Text / Design [Answerd by @Rajkumar Sharma]
- Change API level
- Change Theme
- You may close your current project and Open another new to test that the problem is in your **current project** or in the **Android Studio**.
- Check Manifest